# Assign a series to an axis in jqplot

Tags: javascript, jqplot, timeserieschart, yaxis

I have a jqplot chart with 8 series.  7 of these are normalized in such a way that they look great with the default yaxis.  The last series, however, needs to utilize a secondary yaxis.  There are a ton of examples on utilizing a dual yaxis presentation when there are only two series.

So my question:  Can you assign a specific series to a specific axis?  If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok -- I ended up finding an example in the api docs, where previously I was searching through the examples.

```
{
   series:[
       {color: '#ff4466', lineWidth: 5, label:'good line'},
       {yaxis: 'y2axis', shadow: false, label:'bad line'}
   ]
}
```

The yaxis option is available per series, which allows a specific series to be assigned to a specific yaxis.

I hope this helps someone else.